# Are Azure Web Jobs capable of keeping the task running in background?

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I am currently experiencing difficulties with running a long HTTP request in a Web Job. Same application runs fine when started on local machine. Since I've tried multiple ways of trying to make this work I am now curious if this is possible at all.

My testing code below:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /// [...]Getting configuration and using it in "SendPayload"

            _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            _stopwatch.Start();

            Task.Run(async () => { await SendPayloadAndAwait(configuration); });
            while (_isWaiting)
            {
                if (_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds % 5000 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(".");
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task<string> SendPayloadAndAwait (RequestModel targetRequest)
        {
              /// [...]Preparing client and payload 

              Console.WriteLine("Start");
              Response= curClient.SendAsync(req).Result;
              var endContent = Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
              Console.WriteLine("End");

             _isWaiting = false;
             return "Done";
        }
```

The "End" is never printed in Web Job console, it is an infinite (up to the point of timeout) loop of ".". Is such scenario somehow prohibited?

Comment: Azure Web Apps go to sleep after a period of inactivity by default. Is your Web App containing this web job configured to be "Always On"?

Comment: @mehmetseckin my reasoning was that since there is a constant output the Web App will "stay alive" for the process. Will changing the App Service to Always On be sufficient, or should the job be continous as well?

Comment: According to [this note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#webjob-types), the web app times out after 20 minutes of inactivity, and only the requests to the actual web app resets this timer. The web jobs are executed asynchronously in a separate process, so they don't keep the web app "awake".

Comment: @mehmetseckin I changed to "Always On" and also tried again with the Job being set as Continous, but for both cases the HTTP request seems to be running endlessly. In this particular case I am expecting response in no more than 6-7 minutes, so even that 20 minute mark should be more than needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved at a previous company was by having the long running job in a Web API which was implemented as an Azure Function was

- First call (i.e. /api/StartJob)

  - creates a job entry (in azure table)
  - starts backgound thread
  - returns a 202 [Accepted] status with the job entries Id
- Background thread performs long running task updating job entry with it's progress
- Client Loop (while percentage done < 100)

  - Requests status (i.e. /api/JobStatus)

    - If percentage done = 100 exit loop

This was very successful and reliable providing we had a paid for plan

**The free plans kill the session after approx 5 minutes (by design)**

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable the "Always on" setting to make sure your long-running job doesn't get terminated.

The web app times out after 20 minutes of inactivity, and only the requests to the actual web app resets this timer. The web jobs are executed asynchronously in a separate process, so they don't keep the web app "awake".

Here's a [note from the web jobs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#webjob-types):

> A web app can time out after 20 minutes of inactivity. and only requests to the actual web app can reset the timer. Viewing the app's configuration in the Azure portal or making requests to the advanced tools site (`https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`) doesn't reset the timer. If you set your web app to run continuous or scheduled (timer-trigger) WebJobs, enable the **Always on** setting on your web app's Azure **Configuration** page to ensure that the WebJobs run reliably. This feature is available only in the Basic, Standard, and Premium [pricing tiers](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/app-service/?ref=microsoft.com&utm_source=microsoft.com&utm_medium=docs&utm_campaign=visualstudio).

Comment: I changed to "Always On" and also tried again with the Job being set as Continous, but for both cases the HTTP request seems to be running endlessly. In this particular case I am expecting response in no more than 6-7 minutes, so even that 20 minute mark should be more than needed.

I'll do one more test by moving everything to synchronous execution to determine if this is a task issue or an issue qith request itself.

Comment: Web Job running fully synchronosuly sending the request never finishes in the Web Job- regardless of "Always On" and "Triggered"/"Continous" settings. I'm very confused about this because I cannot see a reason for that not to work. Web Job Console does not return any errors and the code still works when executed locally.

Comment: Upon further research I stumbled on [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05f254a6-9b34-4eb2-a5f7-2a82fb40135f/time-out-after-230-seconds?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) - looks like there's an even lower timeout of 230 seconds for HTTP requests and it is not configurable. The recommendation is to either move to a VM or implement some sort of async pattern.